# Sonarqube Custom Rule- String Literal should not be duplicated, ignored in context of logger

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Trying to extend the below linked Sonarqube rule to ignore the occurrence of a string literal in a logger method.

I am having issues trying to extract method names for methods (which in the context of the Base Visitor Tree may not be scoped as methods from my analysis. But have had some luck looking at methodInvocation type to extract a few method names).

So my question is does any one have a definition list of the Base Visitor Tree elements and how it would see different statements?

e.g. weeLogger.Log(exception, "exception occurred");

or

e.g. logger(exception1, "exception occured);

And as well has anyone done anything similar and share how they extracted out method names from the Base Visitor Tree class for analysis with Sonarqube?

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/StringLiteralDuplicatedCheck.java

Comment: wil be helpful if you can post some relevant codes here and error that you are getting?

Comment: As above, no real errors in code looking for a way to extract a method name and relate it to it's parameters for Sonarqube analysis

Comment: @JordanSmith, what is result of your work? I would like also skip duplication error for loggers

Comment: @michaldo I have added as an answer to the question, my solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get method name**

```
    public class SomeClass extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {
      @Override
      public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit() {
        return ImmutableList.of(Tree.Kind.METHOD);
      }

      @Override
      public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
        MethodTree methodTree = (MethodTree) tree;
        IdentifierTree methodName = methodTree.simpleName();
       // getName from methodName. 

      }

**get invocation method name**
public class SomeClass extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {

    public static IdentifierTree methodName(MethodInvocationTree mit) {
        IdentifierTree id;
        if (mit.methodSelect().is(Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER)) {
            id = (IdentifierTree) mit.methodSelect();
        } else {
            id = ((MemberSelectExpressionTree) mit.methodSelect()).identifier();
        }
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what I am meant to @Override, from my understanding in the super class their is no nodeToVisit() or visitNode() to be overridden?

Comment: It is a class extending SubscriptionVisitor, if you need to use BaseTreeVisitor you can overide  public void visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree tree) or  public void visitMethod(MethodITree tree)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree tree) {
    IdentifierTree id;
    if (tree.methodSelect().is(Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER)){
        id = (IdentifierTree) tree.methodSelect();
    } else {
        id = ((MemberSelectExpressionTree) tree.methodSelect()).identifier();
    }

    if(id.name().matches("(.*)[lL]og(.*)")){
        //Do nothing -> Ignores method with the "log" in them for scanning
    }else {
        scan(tree.methodSelect());
        scan(tree.typeArguments());
        scan(tree.arguments());
    }
}
```

Comment: @michaldo Hopefully this makes sense, just need to add this to the original string literal duplicated rule. Can be extended for any custom logger variable name

Comment: Thanks, I shared this issue here: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/fp-squid-s1192-logging-statements/187